# Installing a Honeywell Wifi thermostat and need a C wire connection

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

[image]My current thermostat is wired as follows and the wires are from my Separate heater and separate AC air handler:

W - From my heat
R - From my heat

Rc - From my AC Handler
Y - From the compressor 
G - From the AC Handler

Do I need to add a wire for the C connection but am unsure whether I need to do that how and where to connect it. Our can I do something else with the G wire?
I have attached a pi of my current schematic, can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you have a spare wire in the cable between your air handler and your thermostat?

Answer (score 1):

In the picture below you can note that the connection labeled with a 7 in a triangle is the "C" of your fan controller. As per your added note to the diagram this is also connected to your A/C unit so there is a common "C" between your A/C and the fan controller. This same place is where you want to connect a spare wire to run for the "C" terminal on your thermostat.

[image]

Comment: Oh, the reason I have posted this is because I want to install a Honeywell 9000 Wifi thermostat and it needs a "C" wire. I had seen a few Youtube videos about alternate  ways to add a "C" wire so I didn't know if I could just connect to the "C" at the 7 (which is on a wire nut above my AC air handler).

Comment: @DaveS - You ask again where to connect for the thermostat. Yet I already said where in my answer.